# Executing a cmd.exe command from a python script

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have a python script `callee.py` which is in a certain directory and that directory is part of the Windows PATH environment variable. In the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe` I can simply execute it as

```
> callee.py arg1 arg2
```

Now, I have another python script `caller.py` in another directory. To execute the first script I would like to use the `subprocess` module like

```
subprocess.Popen("callee.py arg1 arg2")
```

but this does not work, because it does not get that it should actually call `python.exe callee.py ...`. Furthermore,

```
subprocess.Popen("python.exe callee.py arg1 arg2")
```

does not work, because it does not find `callee.py`.

Is there something like `subprocess.Popen` which accepts the very same kind of commands that the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe` does?

Comment: If you want the exact commands of cmd.exe, popen `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this

```
subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe /c callee.py arg1 arg2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is callee.py executable? Or, why don't you give the full path?

```
subprocess.Popen("python.exe c:\full_path\to\callee.py arg1 arg2")
```

Too late, don't consider this answer.